# How to convert a fetch to curl command?

Tags: curl, fetch, devops, fetch-api

this is my **fetch** api call, and I want to know what the equivariant **curl** command would be.

```
fetch("https://192.168.10.0/site/login", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "cache-control": "max-age=0",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not;A Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"91\", \"Chromium\";v=\"91\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
    'X-Forwarded-For': 'doomsday\\\'\'/*, */or 1=1 #'
  },
  "referrer": "https://10.105.100.251/fpc/login?url=",
  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
  "body": "paramURL=&username=spuser&password=test1234&_csrf=1da2a4d5-2173-4030-a8b6-63201b7b1104",
  "method": "POST",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "include"
});
```

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: https://leoek.github.io/fetch-to-curl/playground.html

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Someone gave me this fetch script, and I am try to see if I could get the same response in curl call, but seems it is not. Any ideas ?